# How to get users having birthday today?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I need to send birthday wishes to users in my application.

I have a table `User`, with the column `dateOfBirth`. I need a query to retrieve users having date of birth matching today's date.

For example, if a user has `dateOfBirth` value `1983-11-02 00:00:00`, I have to sent birthday wishes to the user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Table structure would be nice. Also, what have you tried yet?

Comment: Thank you for your replay @BorisSchegolev . in table column name is dateOfBirth and one value is  1983-11-02 00:00:00 . i have to sent birth day wishes to the user.

Comment: Look up date functions in the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html. See how to get the current date, see how to extract day and month and compare.

Comment: The problem is pretty clear, I just wanted to explain why people may downvote your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE MONTH(dateOfBirth) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dateOfBirth) = DAY(NOW());
```

Comment: thank you for your replay @malik. but this query is not working because year is not matched.

Comment: do you have a user whose data of birth lies in current year?

Comment: Haha... **This will select the users who born today..**

Comment: sorry my bad, now check the answer, i am a lil bit drunk now :D

Comment: glad to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

Select the rows with month and day of `dateOfBirth` column is matching with today's.

**Query**

```
select * from `users`
where MONTH(`dateOfBirth`) = MONTH(NOW())
and DAY(`dateOfBirth`) = DAY(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, email 
FROM user
WHERE MONTH(dateOfBirth) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dateOfBirth) = DAY(NOW())
```

Since you have asked the question in hibernate tag.
The above query in hibernate will look like.

```
String hql = "FROM user  WHERE MONTH(dateOfBirth) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dateOfBirth) = DAY(NOW())";

Query q = session.createQuery(hql);

List<user> l = q.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this simple query:

```
SELECT Name from table_name
where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BirthDate)=DAY(CURDATE())
and EXTRACT(DAY FROM BirthDate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing currently is extracting the data from SQL (daily) and composing and email to send the wish manually daily. What if I suggest you a better approach ?

There is an application called [Wishing Application](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) which can send birthday and work anniversary mailer with a breeze.

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.